# Trying to pick the correct test for experiment design

Tags: anova

I’m trying to pick the correct statistical test for my data.

I’m currently testing a drug on rats undergoing cardiac arrest. I have 3 groups (control, vehicle only, drug + vehicle) with 5 samples each. I want to compare the LVDP before going ischemic and 20 minutes post reperfusion.

Here is the setup of the experiment:

[image]

I’m testing a drug on rats that undergo ischemia (i.e. cardiac arrest). The rat’s heart is beating along, then we induce ischemia for 20 minutes. Then we try to recover the heart. After 20 mins of ischemia, we begin reperfusion of the heart with either a drug + vehicle, vehicle, or a control.

As you can see from the image the heart’s LVDP recovered 100% when given the drug + vehicle compared to baseline(LVDP before ischemia). When the heart was given vehicle only the LVDP recovered 75% and when the heart was given the control LVDP recovered 50%.

Which statistical test should I use?

I was thinking of a 2-way ANOVA comparing all 3 groups at 20 minutes post reperfusion vs before ischemia.

Also, I was thinking of doing a 1-way ANOVA at the 20 min post reperfusion mark comparing all 3 groups.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re in a position to pair up your observations. You have a “before” measurement and an “after” measurement, correct? Find the difference between before and after ischemia in each mouse. Now you have three groups. Run 1-way ANOVA. There are the usual issues about checking the assumptions of ANOVA, and which particular test to run will depend on how your observations behave (lack of normality can be much more problematic here than in t-testing, for instance).

I also suspect that you will be curious about comparing the groups to each other, particularly vehicle vs drug/vehicle  and control vs drug/vehicle. You may want to look around Cross Validated and the internet in general for how to do that, and post a new question if you’re still confused.